# How to write mapDispatchToProps when passing data?

Tags: redux

I'm struggling with Redux a little. I'm trying to dispatch an action to redux that will contain data - I can send the dispatch and get a successful response without it, so how do I rewrite the code so I can send data across?

I'm using RN image picker to choose an image. Once the user has chosen an image (in the `getPhotoFromGallery` function), it will get written to the local state where that local state will then be passed into a function dispatch in redux. I'm getting the error `this.props.addImageToPost(imageData) is not a function`

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        imageData: null,
        caption: null,
        base64URI: null
    }

  //choose the photo.
  getPhotoFromGallery = () => {
    const { imageData } = this.state
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, (response)  => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else {
        //send image to redux
        this.setState({ imageData: response });
        this.setState({ base64URI: response.uri });
        this.props.addImageToPost(imageData) // ????
      }
    });
  };

  //show image in component
  showPickedImage() {
    const { imageData } = this.state;

    if (imageData !== null) {
        return (
              <Image
              source={{ uri: imageData.uri }}
              style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: 90, height: 90, borderRadius: 20, marginLeft: 15 }}
              />
        );
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: 90, height: 90, borderRadius: 20, marginLeft: 15, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white', shadowColor: "#000", shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5, }, shadowOpacity: 0.2, shadowRadius: 15, }}
            onPress={this.getPhotoFromGallery}
          >
            <Icon name="camera" size={32} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { image } = this.props;

    return (
        <View style={styles.myFormContainer}>
              {this.showPickedImage()}
        </View>
    );
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { imageData: state.post.imageData }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addImageToPost, // ????
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Connect: Dispatching Actions with mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).

It should be something like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addImageToPost: (imageData) => dispatch({ type: 'ActionType', payload: imageData })
});
```

or if you have an action creator

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addImageToPost: (imageData) => dispatch(myActionCreator(imageData))
});
```

and use it in your component like so

```
else {
    //send image to redux
    this.setState({ imageData: response });
    this.setState({ base64URI: response.uri });
    this.props.addImageToPost(imageData); // ???? correct
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked well apart from needing a ```return``` in the mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @JamesStirrat yeah, was meant to use parenthesis instead of return. The edited answer above should work the same.